# IE: javascript function call on link click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, valums-file-uploader

I have a Javascript function

```
function changeDocument(idxpv, open){
    if(open)
        $("#Upload"+idxpv + " input[type=file]").click();
}
```

and a link

```
<a href="javascript:changeDocument(1,true);" class="close fileupload-exists" 
   data-dismiss="fileupload">change document</a>
```

Now on clicking the link IE9/8 shows the prompt box asking for `LEAVE THE PAGE` and `STAY ON PAGE`

> **EDIT**

The file upload button is generated from Valum's qqFileuploader library.

Could someone guide me whats wrong with it?

Comment: @Padyster if `open === false` what should happen? IE must be trying to follow link and the still something running in the background... try adding `return false` to prevent the browser to change page

Comment: Please provide where exactly said function is defined, if you click stay on this page look for any errors in the console, and provide any debugging that you have done on your own before coming here.

Comment: If You dont see any good reason  to DOWNVOTE, then why did you downvoted without any comments?

Comment: You know that there are multiple people that have a look at the question and that destroy (who made the comment) probably didn't downvote you? Calm down!

Comment: @KevinB The Error console shows the error in the file which has nothing to do with this functionality. It shows error for some line in qqfileuploader.js file..

Comment: Don't use `javascript:` in the `href`.  Attach the event "correctly", you *are* using jQuery, use `.click()`.  Since you are following a link, the browser may think you are leaving the page and my trigger `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: It could possible also be that you can't trigger your `file input` in IE8 / IE9 and create an error or something?

Comment: @RocketHazmat .click() is already used in function with input[type=file].. is there any other way to envoke file upload button?

Comment: @Padyster: I meant to *assign* the event using `.click(function(){})`.

Comment: You might run into some security issues later on, by the way, for triggering the `click` through javascript, rather than having the users actually clicking the input. If you do, look into using a label and moving the input off screen. That way clicking the label (which you can style) will click the input, as well.

Comment: Do you meant this [plugin valums/file-uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader)? Which version are you using? And it [seems the main branch has a different name now](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader).

Answer (score 1):

The call to `$("#Upload1 input[type=file]").click();` is not executed because `open` is undefined.

I copied your code in this document:

- clicking the link calls the function `changeDocument()`
- but since open is undefined the click event is not fired

If you change the calling to this `javascript:changeDocument(1, true);` the click is fired and the file open dialog is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>html 5</title>   
    <script src="../jQuery/jquery_1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        function changeDocument(idxpv, open){
        console.log("idxpv", idxpv);
        console.log("open", open);
        if(open)
            $("#Upload"+idxpv + " input[type=file]").click();
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    <a href="javascript:changeDocument(1, true);" class="close fileupload-exists" 
                data-dismiss="fileupload">change document</a>
    </p>                
    <p id="Upload1">    
    input type=file: <input type="file">                
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes U r Right.. with that conclusion.. but it still doesn't work with IE9/IE8

Comment: I am updating the Question with more details